# Are aptitude get requests cached on a squid proxy

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

In Ubuntu/Debian are apt-get install/upgrade calls cached on a transparent proxy(That is setup with squid).

While I would like to think they are (to save bandwidth in a large network) I haven't found anything that verifies or denies this. Also keep in mind most of my repositories are are setup to use HTTP (which should be cache-able).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apt-mirror does this...that's it's sole purpose

Answer (score 1):

`apt` uses standard HTTP GET requests, which should be cached by Squid the same way as normal browsing.